# wrap li elements in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

i have this piece of code that I am trying to scroll using the jQuery scroller plugin.

```
<ul>
<li style="margin-left:2px;"><span><?php echo a ?></span></li>
<li style="margin-left:2px;"><span><?php echo b ?></span></li>
<li style="margin-left:2px;"><span><?php echo $arrow?></span></li>              
<li style="margin-left:2px;"><span><?php echo c ?></span></li>
<li style="margin-left:2px;"><span><?php echo d ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to get the li elements in the sequence..
`a b c d a1 b1 c1 d1 a2 b2 c2 d2` ... so on...where

```
a1 - stands for ajax refreshed a.
```

any ideas on how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

TRY

```
var listValue = jQuery('ul').children().map( function() {
        return jQuery(this).text();
    }).get();
alert(listValue);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bbYgu/)